# Do decaying particles gain the extra energy "push" they need to do so from the vacuum energy?

Tags: particle-physics, radiation, vacuum

As far as I know, when unstable particles decay they do so because they are no longer able to hold themselves together. So what decides whether or not a particle decays in a particular instant of time must be it's energy content, right?

Unstable particles just need a small "push" over the activation energy barrier before they decay. Does this "push" come from the vacuum energy? Is that why this process appears random because we can't predict what the vacuum energy will be or where it might concentrate itself due to it's random distribution?

If the vacuum energy is not a major contributor to this energy, is it still a contributor? Or does the zero point energy of the vacuum not interact with particles this way?

Comment: I'm as far from an expert as they come, but why would energy conservation cause them to decay?

Comment: My very limited understanding of quantum electrodynamics is that vacuum fluctuations explain why excited atoms decay to lower electronic states. I suppose similar mechanisms are assumed in other field theories.

Comment: I've heard of electrons existing in "virtual" energy states in the context of spectroscopy. Is the miniscule extra energy needed to reach these virtual states provided by the vacuum? In that the excited states themselves are not quite energetic enough to decay until the vacuum fluctuates in such a way that pushes them over the activation barrier?

Comment: There is no activation energy. In QED, the vacuum mixes with the excited state so that it no longer is a real stationary state of the isolated atom.

Comment: Sorry to continue asking questions but what do you mean by a "real stationary state" of the atom? Does QED quantize the electromagnetic field and is a non-real state one which is not allowed as it falls between quantized levels?

Comment: You are trying to describe quantum mechanics in a classical deterministic way. Quantum mechanics is not deterministic. Quantum mechanical processes are random, because randomness is a law of nature. When you say, "this process appears random because we can't predict...", you are on a wrong path of thinking. Things are random and uncertain, not because of our lack of knowledge. This has nothing to do with us. Things are random and uncertain, because randomness and uncertainty are the properties of nature whether we like it or not with our mental bias based on our naive everyday experience.

Comment: Hi Terry  I self study = don't do exercises = very patchy knowledge.  There is is a related question to yours on the right hand side, and it mentions conservation of energy, that's where my reference came from. Hopefully you get an answer,  rather than my naive comment.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a clear understanding of the quantum mechanical nature of "particles" and the way energy conservation and generally conservation laws work at the quantum mechanical frame.

In quantum mechanics bound states are stable if there is no empty lower energy level to which the particles building up the state can end up in.

Take the hydrogen atom and the energy levels which in a semi classical description the electron can occupy. In strict mathematics the energy levels are given by the solution of the potential problem : electron+proton with a coulomb potential V.

[image: hydr]

The stable state of the hydrogen atom for the electron is the n=1. When an electron has been capture at say, n=3, the solution of the equations gives a probability for the electron to fall down to n=1, the energy difference leaving as a photon.  No vacuum or external energy is needed.

This is an easy example. The beta decay of the neutron needs more complicated equations because it involves the strong potential tying up the quarks and the weak interaction that is responsible for the decay of one of the quarks so the neutron turns into a proton, **because the proton is the lowest energy state of three quarks.** No external energy to the specific potential problems apper.

What you have heard about virtual particles is a mishmash  of the mathematical method of calculating ,  the decay probabilities, which used Feynman diagrams. Virtual particles are mathematical representations necessary for calculating complicated more than two  particle states. They have the quantum numbers of the named particles , **but not their mass**. They are off mass shell, a mathematical tool. See this simple Feynman diagram [here.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html)

[image: virtual]

They have nothing to do with  conservation of energy in the overall interaction, i.e. real particles in, real particles out.